# How to invoke DevicePolicyManager methods?

Tags: android

I'm working on a privileged app with multiple android users support. Each user has his own privileges and restrictions. I'm going to invoke `addUserRestriction` method to disallow the user access to external storage. I'v used the following code to do this:

```
 ComponentName admin = getComponentName();
 MethodUtils.invokeMethod(getApplicatioContext(), "addUserRestriction",new Object[]{admin, UserManager.DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA} );
```

but get exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method
```

Answer (score 2):

`Context` whichever it is, doesn't have `addUserRestriction` method, that why you get `NoSuchMethodException`.

You want to get `DevicePolicyManager` instance by invoking

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE)
```

on `Context` instance(probably your Activity). I think you can call `addUserRestriction` directly without reflection.